# Como ajustar tamanho da página customizada para Inkspace para que página inicie nas coordenada (0,0)

Tags: imagem, edição-de-imagens

Bem colocando o tamanho da página de acordo o template:
Largura :420
Altura : 297
Satifaz-se, inicia-se em 0, mas área muito grande para usar ela embutida na página html.Por isso reduzo para o tamanho ocupado pela imagem ,mas feito isso a distância no eixo y não começa em 0 mas aproxidamente em 520. 
Então qual a maneira de configurar isso?